# reading 16-bit greyscale TIFF

Tags: c, tiff

I'm trying to read a 16-bit greyscale TIFF file (BitsPerSample=16) using a small C program to convert into an array of floating point numbers for further analysis.  The pixel data are, according to the header information, in a single strip of 2048x2048 pixels.  Encoding is little-endian.
With that header information, I was expecting to be able to read a single block of 2048x2048x2 bytes and interpret it as 2048x2048 2-byte integers.  What I in fact get is a picture [split into four quadrants](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/unlinked/15_inRT_0p457.png) of 1024x1024 pixels each, the lower two of which contain only zeros.  Each of the top two quadrants look like I expected the whole picture to look: [alt text http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/unlinked/15_inRT_0p457.png](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/unlinked/15_inRT_0p457.png)
If I read the [same file into Gimp](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/unlinked/15_inRT_0p457_gimp.png) or Imagemagick, both tell me that they have to reduce to 8-bit (which doesn't help me - I need the full range), but the pixels turn up in the right places: [alt text http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/unlinked/15_inRT_0p457_gimp.png](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ruw/unlinked/15_inRT_0p457_gimp.png)
This would suggest that my idea about how the data are arranged within the one strip is wrong.  On the other hand, the file must be correctly formatted in terms of the header information as otherwise Gimp wouldn't get it right.  Where am I going wrong?

Output from tiffdump:
15_inRT_0p457.tiff:
Magic: 0x4949  Version: 0x2a
Directory 0: offset 8 (0x8) next 0 (0)
ImageWidth (256) LONG (4) 1<2048>
ImageLength (257) LONG (4) 1<2048>
BitsPerSample (258) SHORT (3) 1<16>
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
Photometric (262) SHORT (3) 1<1>
StripOffsets (273) LONG (4) 1<4096>
Orientation (274) SHORT (3) 1<1>
RowsPerStrip (278) LONG (4) 1<2048>
StripByteCounts (279) LONG (4) 1<8388608>
XResolution (282) RATIONAL (5) 1<126.582>
YResolution (283) RATIONAL (5) 1<126.582>
ResolutionUnit (296) SHORT (3) 1<3>
34710 (0x8796) LONG (4) 1<0>
(Tag 34710 is camera information; to make sure this doesn't somehow make any difference, I've zeroed the whole range from the end of the image file directory to the start of data at 0x1000, and that in fact doesn't make any difference.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem - it was in my C program...

I had allocated memory for an array of longs and used fread() to read in the data:

```
#define PPR 2048;
#define BPP 2;
long *pix;
pix=malloc(PPR*PPR*sizeof(long));
fread(pix,BPP,PPR*PPR,in);
```

But since the data come in 2-byte chunks (BPP=2) but sizeof(long)=4, fread() packs the data densely inside the allocated memory rather than packing them into long-sized parcels.  Thus I end up with two rows packed together into one and the second half of the picture empty.

I've changed it to loop over the number of pixels and read two bytes each time and store them in the allocated memory instead:

```
for (m=0;m<PPR*PPR;m++) {
  b1=fgetc(in);
  b2=fgetc(in);
  *(pix+m)=256*b1+b2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You understand that if StripOffsets is an array, it is an offset to an array of offsets, right?  You might not be doing that dereference properly.

What's your platform?  What are you trying to do?  If you're willing to work in .NET on Windows, [my company sells an image processing toolkit](http://www.atalasoft.com/Products/DotImage/Default.aspx) that includes a TIFF codec that works on pretty much anything you can throw at it and will return 16 bpp images.  We also have many tools that operate natively on 16bpp images.

Comment: Thanks plinth.  StripOffsets points to 0x1000, which is the start of the data - it's exactly 2048x2048x2 bytes away from the end of the file.  
I'm running Linux, and all our data analysis packages are written in C, so I'm afraid I'm not likely to become a customer of yours.